# What is a dynamic alternative to UITableView?

Tags: tables, iphone, ios

Ok, so I have a normal `viewController` that has a `UIScrollView` in it that gives details about distilleries. What I wanted to do was have a list of spirits that are distilled at the distillery that they are reading about. So I attempted to implement a `UITableView` inside of my `UIScrollView`, and after hooking everything up and writing all the delegate and datasource methods I come to find out that a `UITableView` will not work inside of a `UIScrollView`. So does anybody have any ideas as to what kind of User Interface Object I can use to accomplish something like a `UITableView`'s dynamic characteristics? I don't want to use a `UITextView` because it just looks cheap and unstructured. I need something that can dynamically change the number of items shown because not all distilleries will have the same amount of spirits distilled there.

Comment: Closing. It's not getting the attention here because it is not a User Experience issue, it's a technical implementation one. Whether the SO people agree or not it doesn't belong anywhere other than StackOverflow. (But even there it won't get much attention because it's not precise enough. Not liking them because 'UTTableView look cheap and unstructured' isn't enough to base a question on really.